# Import DXF and make it fit work area

Tags: modeling, objects, 3d-view, import

I feel like I've fallen at the first hurdle, importing a DXF file.

By that I mean, I figured out how to enable the dxf import tool, and imported the file I had, but that's about it.

I'm struggling how to manage the workspace and actually view the file I've imported or do anything with it. Maybe I'm doing the import process wrong? Do I import it as a new scene, do I center geometry, etc, etc?

When I selected center geometry I could at least see something, but it looked like my imported file is maybe way to big for the workspace, as all I could see when I zoomed right out, was the first letter or so of some text from the imported file. (see screen shot).

[image: imported dxf in blender]

Ok, I went the other way as you pointed out. Used 0.01, which brought a lot more into view, but still very large, so... used 0.001 which brought more into view, but it doesn't look anything like the plans I see in Autodesk?

[image: incorrectly imported dxf]

To give you an idea of what it should be looking like, this is it in autocad. View from each side, floor plan for ground and 1st floor... two view of the entire building plot, one showing topography and a street view elevation.

[image: how the dxf should look]

Two more Blender screen grabs: this is imported at 0.0001. The first image is relatively close up to the workspace grid, and then second is zoomed out. The closer view looks like I'm getting close to the size I need. In the zoomed out view... I've no idea what is forming the large circular patterns as I can't see anything like that in the original drawings???

Would it help my progress if I removed some of the layers from the original file? I obviously don't need things like drains and internal wood framing, water mains, wiring, etc.

[image] [image]

As you can see from the last screen grab... I've kinda got the plans into the work area, but I don't know what is affecting the view. What is causing this grey shading across the work area?

There was more of it, in ever increasing circles going out from the center, but I removed some by hiding certain layers, but can't seem to view just the plans without this shading?

[image][image][image][image][image][image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it work to hit [A] (toggle select all) and [S] (scale) and scale it in?

Answer (score 2):

### Check scale, center geometry to origin, shift+C, clipping planes...

When importing DXF there are a few options to work with.

[image]

One is the scale. The default settings is scale = 1, wich obiuvsly means that Blender will multiply by this factor the incoming units of the DXF.

So if you had drawn with your vectorial software a square of 2mx2m, blender will import an object of 2unitsx2units.

If you were working in cm, your square shall measure 200. If in blender you are going to work in meters, you must put a 0.01 factor...

This is valid also for the **location** of objects. So it is important to consider also the relative **distance** of the square from the **origin** of the sistem. To avoid problems, if Is possible, I would suggest to move the geometry to the origin in your drawing software.

Another tool that may come useful is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

[image]

It will extend your view till all visible objects are in the 3d view. If it seem that the camera de-zoom too far away, there are probably objects much distant from the origin. Notice that they might come outside of the 3D camera's clipping planes, making them invisible.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.

OK, when doing the import, I set the unit scale to -10.0, and that revealed some more of the text from the plans, but obviously from the screen shot below... it's still huge.

Do I just keep going down in scale on the import until it all comes into view?

Incidentally, I didn't create the plans. They were created by an architect and (after some resistance) they provided the dwg files for me to try and create a 3D render.

Comment: If you don't know the units in which the file was drawn, you'll have to try different values till you guess right. Notice that scale factor is  meant to be a multiplier, so if comes out too big, next time try a smaller value. Don't use negative values, they flip geometry.

Comment: Hi Carlo,

Thanks for your help so far.

I used an import scale of 0.0005, which put all the plans within the grid area. But, if you check the new pics in my original post... there's still something not right. Not sure which element is producing the grey sketchy background and preventing me from seeing the plans properly to work with.

The original file included everything needed for construction, so... do I need to strip away all that I don't need for an external render and save a dxf file with just the minimal data needed?

Any further assistance would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks,

Del.

Comment: Maybe is better to continue in a chat room so I can ask you some things.. Would you join me there (http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26021/import-dxf-and-make-it-fit-work-area)?

Comment: Ah... because I'm new to this forum, it won't let me use the chat room.

Comment: I can see what you're writing, but can't respond. :(

Comment: Eh, you're right.. mumble, what we can do...

Comment: OK, we'll write here and than we'll delete all if needed...

Comment: What happens if you "Zoom to extent" (double click on the scrool wheel button) in AutoCAD? Is the scene wide or small?

Comment: To be honest, I'm still not sure why architectural plans in cad format are restricted by the architect.  could understand if it was a groundbreaking design, but... just for a regular house???

Personally... they haven't specifically said I can't share them, just that they were only to be used to produce a 3D render for the property owner's website, so... I would consider this part of the process.

Comment: Anyway... in CAD, if I double click on the scroll wheel, it fits the plans to the visible area of the screen.

Comment: No, don't do it if you are not sure. A thief might use them to obtain info...

Comment: Ok, and everything is ok in that view? Nothing strange? just plans?

Comment: I've added a screen grab of what I see in CAD when I double click on mouse wheel.

Comment: Now, select all you se, and COPY them in the origin of a new file. In this way we'll get rid of the hidden objects..

Comment: Next step could be explode all the object in AutoCAD. A large number of autocad primitives (ellipses above all) are not correctly handled by the DXF importer, so by exploding we'll simplify a bit the geometry...blocks, text, polylines..shall all becomes lines.

Comment: Well... I'm not sure I've done that right. I tried to copy all that was visible and put in a new document, then save as dxf and import in Blender, but still... new screen grab I've added shows there's a lot of data that seems to originate from way outside of the plans as they display in CAD.

Sorry... I'm new to CAD, too. I've always been very quick to pick up new software and instinctively find my way around, but this stuff... it's scrambling my brain. LOL.

Comment: Is it impossible to delete those big objects? Maybe we'll lose some geometry, but at least we'll se the plans

Comment: Gimme a moment, let me see.

I did try deleting some layers, but it wouldn't let me.

Comment: Just thought... might help to show you what's been imported. See latest pic.

Comment: That's OK, these should be the layers that once in blender are considered as groups..

Comment: That's what is in Blender. If I hide some layers, it removes some of those large grey areas from the screen, but... I can't seem to remove all the large grey areas.

Comment: Try to Select all by pressing A, than Alt + C to convert everithing to a mesh, than "set origin to geometry" ...now you should be able to select the bigger object so we can see what is behind and if there are other problems in addition to the circles

Comment: OK, I did that, but couldn't discern any significant change. What I did do, was hide more layers and the layer labelled 'buildings' once hidden, seemed to remove the remaining grey background area, which seemed counter intuitive.

So... I can see more of the plans now, but despite using the same import scale I had earlier... it doesn't all fit within that work area grid.

Comment: Those dotted lines means that you have some parented objects. Delete hierarcy by select all with "A" and Alt+P ->clear parent and keep trasformations

Comment: OK... did that. It removed the dotted lines.

Comment: If I zoom out, there's still a lot of stuff that seems almost disconnected from the main body of the plans.

But... am I almost at the point where I can reduce the focus of the plans to the work area, and maybe start putting them together into 3D configuration?

Comment: Actually Carlo... you're in Italy, I'm in the UK... it's late by both our clocks, so... just leave it there. As and when you get a moment at a more reasonable hour, if there's anything you can add to help me get on the way to my first 3D render... I'd be very grateful.

Until then.... thank you very, very much for taking the time to help me out so far. I really do appreciate it.

Del.

Comment: If you can easly select the "correct objects" you can invert selection and delete the others

Comment: Yeah! See you soon...

Comment: I'll experiment with hiding/showing layers to see if I can identify the stuff I need, and the stuff I don't.

I'll post screen grabs with the results so that you can see how far I've got when you check in again.

Comment: Added one final screen grab for where I'm at.

Now I'm going to go sleep, before my head explodes. :)

Comment: Hi Carlo. Been doing some reading this morning and have been wondering... have I exported the dwg files as the best version of dxf for Blender to work with?

By default I selected to export the files as 'AutoCAD 2013 DXF' but... there's 4 or 5 other options, ranging from AutoCAD 2000 to 2010. There's also a version called R12/LT2 DXF. So... should I be generating a different version of the dxf file for better results?

Also, from what I've read... is it better if I have each element of the plans in a separate file? One for each floor, one for each side, etc?

Comment: Hi! I think that 2013 DXF is the best option you have. Yes, cerntely separing each plans would help. Try also to run the command "purge" in autocad to clean up the file a bit. The main problem is that the cfircle and ellipse primitive are not handled correctly, so the are overscaled and in the wrong location. As they are imported as 2D curves they create those grey plans.

Comment: OK, never used the Purge command before... see the new screen grab I added to my post... is there anything I should, or shouldn't check or tick on that command window?

Comment: I decided to tick all the boxes and purge all, saved a new dxf file and imported it into Blender... still all the elements linked outside of the main plan.

I had no idea it was going to be this difficult just to get some plans imported. Previous videos I'd watched seemed to look a lot easier. :(

Comment: Ehh, it dependends of how it's your file made, but usually what you see will not be deleted. So purge all...

Comment: If you encounte so many difficulties, maybe you can: -import dwg to 3dsMax and then export in OBJ -use a different format (ex:FBX) - print the layouts out with a dwg to pdf than import pdf in Inkscape and save as SVG

Comment: The plans were originally suppl;ied to me in pdf format, but |I asked for the dwg files as I assumed they would be better for importing into 3D modelling software.

Comment: If you don't need to be precise you can even import the layouts as backgrond images to use as references...it depends on what is your purpose. DXF preserve the max amount of information (layers, splines, beziers...) but if there are problems and you don't need such precision, maybe a more simple file-exange forma is better suited

Comment: OK, perhaps I should have explained my end goal... I would like to produce an external render of the property in the plans. No internal details, just a conceptual view of how the property would look when complete.

So obviously, plans that include drainage, water mains, manhole locations, etc... I don't need.

Comment: OK, now I'm courios, so if you trust me, I'll send you a link to a temporary mail where you can send me the dwg so I could tell you what's wrong with it. Once we've solved the problem Iìll destroy all the evidences

Comment: Do you use Skype, Carlo?

Comment: importing DXF can speed up a lot with the modeling Yes I use it. Not very often... I'm not sure if I'll be able to remenber tha login

Comment: I'll contact you on skype...gimme 10 minutes

Comment: I should have sent you the invite

Comment: Accepted your Skype request.